# How to implement multiple parallel queue in RabbitMQ and Node.js?

Tags: node.js, queue, rabbitmq, message-queue, task-queue

I am currently designing a small app that require to have multiple sync queue with delay, but across multiple users it is require to be async. Here's an example in table

```
Queue1  | Queue2  | Queue3  | Queue4  | QueueN
        |         |         |         |
2s      | 4s      | 1s      | 8s      | Ns
1s      | 3s      | 3s      | 5s      | Ns
3s      | 2s      | 5s      | 1s      | Ns
6s      | 1s      | 6s      | 2s      | Ns

...and so on...
```

I tried to replicate with rabbitMq and got it working with the delay for 1 queue, but I can't find away to make process work asynchorously with multiple queues. ( those on the same queue will run *one by one* and those on different queue can run at the same time if there are resource available)

As I research it is a mix between `task queue` and `topic` type of message. But with topic message it require to attach a topic name to worker but in my case the queue name can be infinite and i can't list out the list of topic to be listen in a queue.

Is there anyway possible using rabbitMq, or any other kind of queue, to archive this result?

Thank you